# Semantic UI: Access search component selected item

Tags: javascript, semantic-ui

I'm having a problem using the search component.

What I want to do is being able to access the selected element data but it looks there are some timing issues and/or I'm doing things in the wrong way.

This is my code:

```
$('.ui.search.popup-project-changeCustomer').search(
{
    type : 'standard',
    source : $scope.customers,
    searchFields : [
        'title',
        'description'
    ],
    onSelect : function(event) {
        $scope.project.customer = event.target.value;
        $scope.changeCustomer(token);
        return 'default';
    }
});
```

The problem resides in the onSelect event and basically I can access the `target.value` but what I get is what the user typed in and not what the search component puts into the input.

What's the best practice to actually get the data (like title, description etc..) of the user selected element? I guess I'm doing something wrong here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I know that this is probably not a complete answer but more informations can be found here: https://github.com/Semantic-Org/Semantic-UI/issues/1634

I asked the same questio and looks like this issue will be solved in 1.8.0.